# Reading file using Spring Integration and want to use filter for ordering and file pick up

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to implement a scenario, where the spring integration application running on multiple pods in the Kubernetes environment trying to read the files from one directory.

1. While reading I am applying a lock on the file but with the lock applied I am not able to process the file and rename or move the file to another folder.
   **file:nio-locker/**
2. Once I release the lock I am able to read the file and process the file.

```
FileLocker locker = new NioFileLocker();
locker.unlock(file);
```

3. To avoid any conflict, after releasing the lock, two instances read the same data file I want to create a temp file with the file name and prefix _processing.
4. So any file adapter reading the file from the directory for processing should not read the file which has got another file with the file name and  _processing suffix.

summary:

a. file adapter (will pick the file which is not locked and does not contain another file with _processing prefix ).
b. Read the file take the lock.
c. create the temp file with the file name and _processing prefix.
d unlock the file and process it with a transformer and batch job.
e. another pod reading the file from the directory will check the file which is not locked and does not have a temporary file.

```
 <file:inbound-channel-adapter
             channel="input"
             directory="C:/Users/*****/TestFileIntegration/inputWithData"
             auto-startup="true"
             prevent-duplicates="true"
             queue-size="10"
             use-watch-service="true">
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="1" />
        <file:nio-locker/>
     </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I need help for two points
**1. Reading files in a way, code picks the oldest file first and the latest file lasts.**
**2. Filter and read files which do not have a temporary file with the name fileName_Processing and not locked.**

Answer (score 0):

Consider to not use a `<file:nio-locker/>`, but instead configure a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with a shared `MetadataStore`. So, every instance of your application is going to consult that store first before poling the file. And if there is an entry for a file, it is going to be skipped by the current instance: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/file.html#file-reading

For the order you are seeking there is a `comparator` option on the  `<file:inbound-channel-adapter>`:

```
<xsd:attribute name="comparator" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Specify a Comparator to be used when ordering Files. If none is provided, the
order will be determined by the java.io.File implementation of Comparable.  MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE with queue-size.
                ]]></xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```